Locked out of EC2 Ubuntu Instance after enabling MFA
I tried adding MFA on my EC2 Ubuntu instance, basically, I followed the steps here:
Help! cant seem to get 2FA to work for my AWS ec2 SSH
Except I did not comment @include common-auth in the sudo nano /etc/pam.d/sshd directory.
Now whenever I try to ssh into my EC2 instance, I get asked of a password. I always log in with just the PEM key and I didn't set any password for the account. I tried submitting a blank password but it doesn't work and I get the following error message: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).
Hiow can I regain access to the server? Please HELP!

This problem has nothing to do with Ubuntu. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929267/locked-myself-out-of-ssh-with-ufw-in-ec2-aws

Thanks but I believe the issue in that post is different from mine, so I don't think the solution suggested there applies.

You go through Amazon-EC2's web site and access your system. Then fix whatever the problem you created, just as the linked Q&A says.
